# how to create start date and end date picker in one textbox using jQuery and the output should be like 23 Dec 2019 - 23 Nov 2019 inside the textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(function() {
  $('input[name="datefilter4"]').daterangepicker({
  autoUpdateInput: false,
  locale: {
     cancelLabel: 'Clear'
   }
 });

 $('input[name="datefilter4"]').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
  $(this).val(picker.startDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY') + ' - ' + picker.endDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY'));
 });

 $('input[name="datefilter4"]').on('cancel.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
  $(this).val('');
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-daterangepicker/3.0.5/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />


<input type="text" name="datefilter4" value="" class="date-selection"/>
```

[image]

I need the start date and end date range picker in one textbox and the output should like 23 Dec 2019 - 23 Nov 2019

Answer (score 2):

Use `DD MMM YYYY` format

```js
$(function() {
  $('input[name="datefilter4"]').daterangepicker({
    autoUpdateInput: false,
    showDropdowns: true,
    locale: {
      cancelLabel: 'Clear'
    }
  });

  $('input[name="datefilter4"]').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
    $(this).val(picker.startDate.format('DD MMM YYYY') + ' - ' + picker.endDate.format('DD MMM YYYY'));
  });

  $('input[name="datefilter4"]').on('cancel.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
    $(this).val('');
  });
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />


<input type="text" name="datefilter4" value="" class="date-selection" />
```

Comment: also month and year should be like dropdown

Comment: @KarthikReddy check now