# How to show start date and end date in one text field as well as the months and years in a dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(function() {
 $('input[name="datefilter1"]').daterangepicker({
      autoUpdateInput: false,
      locale: {
         cancelLabel: 'Clear'
    }
 });

 $('input[name="datefilter1"]').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
      $(this).val(picker.startDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY') + ' - ' + picker.endDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY'));
 });
 
    $('input[name="datefilter1"]').on('cancel.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
    $(this).val('');
 });
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css"/>


<input type="text" id="picker" class="date-selection">
```

[image]

the output should be like as I shown in the above image, and also the months and years should be like dropdowns.

Comment: and the date format should display as 24 Dec 2019

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to create start date and end date picker in one textbox using jQuery and the output should be like 23 Dec 2019 - 23 Nov 2019 inside the textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59450570/how-to-create-start-date-and-end-date-picker-in-one-textbox-using-jquery-and-the)

Answer (score 2):

add **showDropdowns: true** in configuration

```js
$('#demo').daterangepicker({
    "showDropdowns": true,
    "startDate": "12/18/2019",
    "endDate": "12/24/2019",
    "maxDate": new Date()
}, function(start, end, label) {
  console.log('New date range selected: ' + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' to ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' (predefined range: ' + label + ')');
});
```

```html
<input type="text" name="datetimes" id="demo" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />
```

Comment: and in end date we need to disable the  dates from tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [Litepicker](https://wakirin.github.io/Litepicker/). It's powerful, lightweight, no dependencies

```js
let input = document.getElementById('litepicker');
let now = new Date();
let picker = new Litepicker({
  element: input,
  // format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
  format: 'DD MMM YYYY',
  singleMode: false,
  numberOfMonths: 2,
  numberOfColumns: 2,
  showTooltip: true,
  scrollToDate: true,
  startDate: new Date(now).setDate(now.getDate() - 1),
  endDate: new Date(now),
  // minDate: new Date(now).setDate(now.getDate() - 7),
  // maxDate: new Date(now).setDate(now.getDate() + 7),
  setup: function(picker) {
    picker.on('selected', function(date1, date2) {
      console.log(`${date1.toDateString()}, ${date2.toDateString()}`)
    })
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" name="datetimes" id="litepicker" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/litepicker/dist/litepicker.js"></script>
```

Comment: Have you guys had any luck having litepicker popup after a button click and then it populates a input field next to it? In my case I want to populate asp:TextBox with the picked date?